# No output while using data for storing and retrieving data

Tags: jquery

I am newbie to JS and tring my hand in JS. I got no data while storing and retriving data in html using data-*.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
$('#myElId').data('nameYourData', { foo: 'bar' });

var myData = $('#myElId').data('nameYourData');
document.write(myData);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the `#myElId` element? You can't store data against an element that isn't in your markup. Assuming the element exists in your real html, the script that references it would need to appear afterwards (or use a document ready handler).

Comment: Firstly, don't use `document.write`, use DOM methods to update text. Secondly, where is `#myElId`?

Comment: I got this example from here  http://gotoanswer.stanford.edu/?q=How+to+get+element+content+by+id+from+HTML+object+by+JavaScript+%28+JQuery+%29

Comment: Yes, the data setting and getting is not the problem. You just need an object to set and get it from

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Here is YOUR script - it needs its own set of script tags -->
<script>
$(function() { // on page load
  $('#myElId').data('nameYourData', { foo: 'bar' });
  // and later  
  var myData = $('#myElId').data('nameYourData');
  $("#showMyData").text(myData.foo);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myElId">Some element</div>
<div id="showMyData"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**RUNNING Example**

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  $('#myElId').data('nameYourData', { foo: 'bar' });
  // and later  
  var myData = $('#myElId').data('nameYourData');
  $("#showMyData").text(myData.foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myElId">Some element</div><br/>
MyData:<div id="showMyData"></div>
```

Array:

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  $('#myElId').data('nameYourData', ["foo","bar"]);
  // and later  
  var myData = $('#myElId').data('nameYourData');
  $("#showMyData").text(myData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myElId">Some element</div><br/>
MyData:<div id="showMyData"></div>
```

Comment: I got no ouput when i used the same code in HTML.   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() { // on page load
  $('#myElId').data('nameYourData', { foo: 'bar' });
  // and later  
  var myData = $('#myElId').data('nameYourData');
  $("#showMyData").text(myData.foo);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myElId">Some element</div>
<div id="showMyData"></div>
</body>
</head>
</html>

Comment: You need to download and save jquery.js in the same folder as the html or use the cdn `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` as done in the example

Comment: I just edited my code but i got no output.   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
$(function() { // on page load
  $('#myElId').data('nameYourData', { foo: 'bar' });
  // and later  
  var myData = $('#myElId').data('nameYourData');
  $("#showMyData").text(myData.foo);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myElId">Some element</div>
<div id="showMyData"></div>
</body>
</head>
</html>

Comment: See update. You need two sets of script tags! Copy the HTML at the top, the stuff under the **EXAMPLE** header is a running example

Comment: Yes. See updated example. the question is why? You can save the array in the script instead of using a data attr